# Is it possible to show activity as a list view in other activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-xml

I want to call one activity as a list view which is having some data to other activity as a list view.

Comment: Use fragment for this, not Activity

Comment: you really need to know the meaning of an Activity in android first!

Comment: this is not possible in Activity use Fragment in Activity

Comment: It is really unclear what u r asking be specific what exactly u want and what u have tried so far?

Comment: First tell us, what is Activity and why do we use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is a fragment...define the listview in the fragment and you can use ViewPager in the activity to display the fragment or multiple such fragments.